# How to modify the command line used to renew a certificate using WACS

Tags: windows, certificate, lets-encrypt

I have been using Let's Encrypt certificates for some of my domains/servers for a while, using the win-acme client for Windows for the generation and renewal.

My problem is: every renewal I have to run the `wacs.exe` manually again, using the force renewal option, having passed the `--acl-fullcontrol` command line option and the account I need to have full control to read the certificates.

I haven't found how to change the command line used by WACS for the renewal so that option (`--acl-fullcontrol`) is added there, and I can forget about that. I have looked everywhere but without any luck. The `.json` file for each domain doesn't include any option that appears to be related to that, the only thing I have found is the `"PrivateKeyExportable":true` in the `settings.json` file, but nothing to configure a specific account to grant permissions.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simpler that I thought.

Using that command line option, you just need to enter and Modify the task/certificate where you want to change the option. For instance, modify the options related to the Store of the certificate. It is not needed to change anything, as far as I can see, you just need to enter, set the same values as they have, and the task will include the new command line option.

I have yet to see if it effectively changes the ACL for the private key, as expected, but at least the solution to this question is this.